# JQuery add css not inline

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet, inline

I want to add css with JQuery.
I've try this :

```
$('#imageMenu').css("display", "block");
```

but the generate code is inline. Can I just add css without made inline style? 
I want to add style in my stylesheet. It's possible? I search on the internet  but I not found.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here [Add Rules to Stylesheets with JavaScript](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets)

Comment: Use something like this: `sheet.insertRule("header { float: left; opacity: 0.8; }", 1);`

Answer (score 5):

what is the reason you are trying to do it? if you know the css code you need from the first place you can add it to your stylesheet file and then use the [JQuery addClass function](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

CSS (insert it to your stylesheet file):

```
.block
{
    display: block;
}
```

JQuery (make the action):

```
$('#imageMenu').addClass('block');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2dazvud6/

**improve of [Toby:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837985/toby)** Keep in mind, anything done with JavaScript will be at least partially inline. In this example the class you add is added inline. This is simply because of how JavaScript works. It is client sided and the client does not have access to your website to make edits. If you need a strong level of control you may have to consider using JavaScript/Ajax and a sever sided scripting language instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rules to the stylesheet using Javascript: For example:

```
myStyle.insertRule('#blanc { color: white }', 0);
```

Note that this won't make changes to the stylesheet file itself, just
the stylesheet that is loaded in memory. More info can be found here: [CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule)